# VBA Replacing New-Lines (Enter) with space in a string

Tags: excel, vba, newline

I want to replace all enters in a string with space.
for example code should turn:

```
line 1 content
line 2 content

line 3 content
```

into:

```
line 1 content line 2 content line 3 content
```

Here is a real sample text:

Sell GBPCHF @ 1.15910

Take profit 1 at 1.15710

Take profit 2 at 1.15410

Take profit 3 at 1.14910

Stop loss at 1.16510

Any help would be grate!

Comment: Are those lines in the same cell?  Have those lines been obtained by pressing `Alt + Enter`?

Comment: The text may copy from different sources so it may be Alt + Enter or something else.

Comment: But, is the text in discussion in a single cell? If yes, are there spaces (empty lines) between two consecutive lines? I am looking at your example and I cannot understand this aspect...

Comment: I updated my answer code to work for `VbVrLf` and `VbLf`, also. But, it works for a string in a cell (or a string itself), without empty lines...

Comment: Yes, Its is a single cell and it may be empty lines between the consecutive lines!

Comment: So, it only may be, meaning that they may also not be... Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @FanDuru: Unfortunately the new code does not do the job also

Comment: Do you mean, the updated code? Please, refresh the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about a string in a cell, please use the next code:

```
Sub testReplaceLfAndAddSpace()
   Dim strTest As String
   strTest = Replace(ActiveCell.value, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
   If UBound(Split(ActiveCell.value, vbCrLf)) <> 0 Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).value = Replace(strTest, vbCrLf, " ")
   Else
      strTest = Replace(ActiveCell.value, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)
      ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).value = Replace(strTest, vbLf, " ")
   End If
End Sub
```

It will return the result in the next cell, on the same row.

Comment: ...........perhaps `vbCrLf`

Comment: @Gary's Student: `VbLf` should be enough for lines inserted using `Alt + Enter`. In such cases, `VbCrLf` will not do the job... Now, it depends on what kind of string does he have. It looked (for me) more probable to be something manually built. But, who knows? He will (probably) tell us if the code does not do the job... :)

Comment: This code does not do the job. I added a real sample text to the question

Comment: The updated code works with `WbCrLf` and `WbLf`, too. It also solves the case of **one empty line** (existing, or not) between the consecutive lines. Refresh the page, please...